# how to test to see if a humidistat temperature sensor is working

Tags: hvac

I have an April Air 600 humidistat with an outside temperature sensor. What is the procedure to test a temperature sensor to see if it is working.

Comment: You want to know if the actual sensor is functional, or you want to check and see if it  is hooked up and "doing something" to the system?

Answer (score 1):

I have an Aprilaire Model 55 TCH (Temperature Compensating Humidistat).  Do you have an ohmmeter?  This is what I found in my notes:
[image]

I'm thinking the sensors haven't changed between models.  I would measure it at the TCH to make sure there isn't any discontinuity between the sensor and the TCH.

Comment: if in need of an "ohmeter", one can get the cheapest possible multi-meter, sometimes they even give them away at harbor fright...

Comment: thanks steve I do have an ohm meter. I assume I disconnect from the humidistat and test for resistance and compare to chart to see if it is functioning. then how do I test to see if it is affecting the humidistate

Comment: Yes to testing the sensor with an ohmmeter.   I keep my humidity on the 'edge' of causing condensation on windows.  Occasionally, when the temperature drops very quickly, I'll see just a bit of condensation which disappears as the humidifier backs off the humidity because of the colder temperature outside.  That is how I know it is working.  I don't know how to actually test it.